# How To Create Conditional for Unique Validation (UPDATE/PATCH) on Form Request

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, unique

I'm trying to get my controller cleaner by moving 'validation request' into a form request called 'BookRequest'.

The problem is on the update process, I try to create a condition to check, if it PATCH or POST with the following codes

#### MyRequest.php

```
public function rules()
    {

        // Check Create or Update
        if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') 
        {
            $a_rules = 'required|string|size:6|unique:books,column2,' .$this->get('id');
            $b_rules = 'sometimes|string|size:10|unique:books,column3,' .$this->get('id');
        }

        else 
        {
            $a_rules = 'required|string|size:6|unique:books,column2';
            $b_rules = 'sometimes|string|size:10|unique:books,column3';
        }

        return [
            'column1'             => 'required|string|max:100',
            'column2'             => $a_rules,
            'column3'              => $b_rules,
            'column4'    => 'required|date',
            'column5'            => 'required|in:foo,bar',
            'column6'        => 'required',
            'column7'       => 'required',
            'column8'       => 'required',
        ];

    }
```

`.$this->get('id')` it failed, the form still treat the unique on the update.

#### Controller@update

```
public function update($id, BookRequest $request)
{
    $book = Book::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $book->update($request->all());
    return view('dashboards.book');
}
```

#### Controller@edit

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $book = Book::findOrFail($id);


    return view('dashboards.edit', compact('book'));
}
```

#### Controller@create

```
public function create()
{

    return view('dashboards.create');
}
```

#### Controller@store

```
public function store(BookRequest $request)
{


    $input = $request->all();
    $book = Book::create($input);

    return redirect('dashboards/book/index');
}
```

I try the alternative `.$book->id`, and it throw me an *ErrorException* *Undefined variable: book*

Any suggestion? I'm using Laravel 5.2 by the way

Comment: what dd($this->get('id'))  gives

Comment: @Sohel0415 do you mean i should try `dd($this->get('id'))`? it gives me a `null`

Comment: thats why the form still treat the unique on the update.

Comment: show us your controller code that we can help

Comment: @Sohel0415 kindly check my controller

Comment: what is your url?? Show your url part from route.

Comment: @Sohel0415 for the edit/PATCH dashboards/book/{book}/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **book** as your route parameter but trying to get with **id**. try this-

```
if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') 
    {
        $a_rules = 'required|string|size:6|unique:books,column2,' .$this->route()->parameter('book');
        $b_rules = 'sometimes|string|size:10|unique:books,column3,' .$this->route()->parameter('book');
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: where i should put the code? i put it before `if ($this->method() == 'PATCH')` and it still the same

Comment: thank you the form seem sucess when update, it saved to the database, but there is a problem, it redirect me to an error page `E:\...testrequest\storage\framework\views\...` when i submit the update form, but when i go the the existing page on different tab on browser /dashboards/book/{book} just fine   any suggestion?

Comment: is your update function working correctly, did you checked your db records??

Comment: i'm not sure about the update function but it works well before i moved the validation to the form request.  as you can see on the controller@update

Comment: what do get by dd($this->method()) if you put on top of your rules method

Comment: the page say that it is "PATCH" i try to move the update view to book/index and it work. so i assume that the problem occurs only on the single page of the book/{book}

Comment: nice work, then try to debug your controller function line by line,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162274/discussion-between-yudy-ananda-and-sohel0415).

Comment: the problem is on return vew,  `return view('dashboards.book', compact('book'));` works like a charm :) thank you